# set receiver emain on ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, email

I have set the receiver email address but when I tried to use it on my phone the receiver address is empty and you have to fill it on manually. I think the code is fine I don't know what the problem

```
CODE:
Intent mail = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "..@gmail.com");
mail.setType("plain/text");
startActivity(mail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill all the available options like Subject, Text.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.setType("plain/text");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "Receiver@gmail.com");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Subject Here");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body Part here");

startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Hope you have given all the permissions Correctly.

Some references. [Link 1](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Comment: What permissions should I use? I think I only used _INTERNET.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] reciver  = new String[]{
                        "reciver01@gmail.com",
                        "reciver02@gmail.com",
                         ...
                     };
mailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, reciver);
```

Comment: Always format your Questions && answers properly. Use the tools provided while you answer. This helps in easy understanding of code. Unformatted code though be v.good but people most likely to avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should insert the receiver email here:

```
mail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "receiver@gmail.com");
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. That's where I inserted it. But when I use it on my device the receiver address is empty.